# How to find IP address of domains?

Tags: linux, ip, domain

I should find IP addresses of some domains which are listed in a txt file. Firstly I need to read them and then find IP addresses .

Output should be given format.

> domain_name : IP Address

Comment: Ask your dns server. Hint: `man dig`

Comment: How are they listed in the file? What if an entry has more than one IP?

Comment: They are listed line by line. If a domain has more than one IP they can be writte like domain_name : IP Address1  IP Address2  IP Address3 ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to get an IP address for a given hostname:

```
$ dig +short example.com
93.184.216.34
$ host example.com
example.com has address 93.184.216.34
example.com has IPv6 address 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
```